# how to arrange 4 cartesian points in clockwise or anti-clockwise order

Tags: coordinate-systems

I am implementing a program in C which requires that given 4 points should be arranged such that they form a quadrilateral.(assume no three are collinear)
Currently , I am ordering the points in the order of their slope with respect to origin.
See https://ibb.co/cfDHeo .
In this case a,b,c,d are in descending order of slope but on joining a to b , b to c , c to d , d to a - I don't get a quadrilateral .
So my method fails in such cases.

I need suggestion.

Thanks.

Comment: It is not guaranteed that the [convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) of four points contains all four of the points.  Consider what happens when you take three of the points and form the triangle with them and the fourth point happens to be in the interior of that triangle.  E.g. as [pictured here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1d/Finite-3-regular-graph-4-vertices.png?1529891524346).

Comment: What is your definition of quadrilateral?  As long as the points are distinct you can connect them in any order.  This will be a closed curve composed of four segments  Some people exclude those that are not convex.  For some positions of the points you cannot escape that.  Some people exclude ones that have the segments intersecting.  I give an approach to avoid that.  Please clarify what you are looking for.

Comment: @Ross Millikan , I am okay with convex or non-convex quadrilateral as long as its opposite sides don't intersect. if atan2 does tan inverse then consider a square centered at origin such that its side are parallel to axes . In this case - won't atan2 give -45 degree for two points (of diagonal1) and +45 degree for other two (of diagonal2). If I sort that then I won't get desired quadrilateral.

Comment: @Ross Millikan :- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2 seems to indicate that atan2 will give +45 degree for point in first quadrant and -135 degree for point in third quadrant . point in second quadrant will give +135 degree and -45 degree for point in fourth quadrant . Thus ascending order  will give 3,4,1,2 i.e anticlockwise. Okay for me . See my question about getting centroid in comment ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to order the points, especially if they form on concave polygon. For this case, the problem is easy. Say you have points $a,b,c,d$ in this order. Check the intersection between the two diagonals, $ac$ and $bd$, as segments, not infinite lines. That means that the intersection is between $a$ and $c$. If it is, you have a convex quadrilateral. If not, you have two options: it is either a concave quadrilateral, or the sides intersect, like in your case. Either way, if you swap any adjacent points (say the first two), you will get a quadrilateral. So $bacd$ in your case is OK. If you swap points on a concave quadrilateral you get a different concave quadrilateral.

Comment: I was thinking on this lines that if we consider all pair of 2 points for given 4 points then two pairs will be diagonal and other 4 pairs will be sides . So the question is how to decide if a pair of points form a diagonal ? One way is to find equation of line joining the taken pair (call it ad), and the equation of line joining other 2 points . Now we have to find the solution of these 2 equations then we will get coordinates of a point (say o) . I will find distance oa and od if any of them is > distance 'ad' then we can say that taken pair is not a diagonal. Will that work ?

Comment: Only if you guarantee that the quadrilateral is convex. Check diagonals for a polygon (-1,0), (0,5),(1,0),(0,6). Also, implied in your calculation, the case where o is at infinity, means that the two lines are parallel. Then you need to check other pairs of points.

Comment: you gave example of this https://ibb.co/g0tbQT which clearly shows a non-convex quadrilateral . pretty nice example .

Answer (score 2):

You can just order them by the angle from the centroid to each point, measured from the $+x$ direction.  The [Atan2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) function does this nicely.  The resulting quadrialteral may not be convex, but it will not be self-intersecting.

Comment: I think that's exactly the case in the picture. If ordered in increasing angle $dcba$, the sides intersect.

Comment: @Andrei  good point.  I updated specifying that you measure from the centroid.  Thanks..

Comment: Correct. Note that if the quadrilateral is not convex, any order is fine. Two points might be at the same angle.

Comment: @Andrei:  I think OP wants to avoid self-intersection but not being convex is OK.  In that case if there are two points at exactly the same angle either order works fine.

Comment: BTW , I just want to make a quadrilateral . need not be convex.
for coordinate of centroid - should I take (x1+x2+x3+x4)/4 (similiarly for y) ?

Comment: Yes, that is what I was thinking for the centroid.